# Regex in sed to convert ##XXX## to ${XXX}

Tags: regex, sed

I need to use sed to convert all occurences of `##XXX##` to `${XXX}`. X could be any alphabetic character or '_'. I know that I need to use something like:

```
's/##/\${/g'
```

But of course that won't work properly, as it will convert `##FOO##` to `${FOO${`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a shot at a better replacement regex:

```
's/##\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)##/${\1}/g'
```

Or if you assume exactly three characters :

```
's/##\([a-zA-Z_]\{3\}\)##/${\1}/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

- Encapsulate the alpha and '_' within '\(' and '\)' and then in the right side reference that with '\1'.

  '+' to match one or more alpha and '_' (in case you see ####).

  Add the 'g' option to the end to replace all matches (which I'm guessing is what you want to do in this case).

```
's/##\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)##/${\1}/g'
```

Comment: + is not a standard operator in sed -- maybe in GNU sed.

Comment: And there was no mention of digits.

Comment: Yes, + is an operator in GNU sed, not maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
s/##\([^#]*\)##/${\1}/
```

BTW, there is no need to escape $ in the right side of the "s" operator.

Comment: The [^#] is not an accurate match for a string of "any alphabetic character or '_'".

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/##\([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_]\)##/${\1}/'
```

The `\(...\)` remembers...and is referenced as `\1` in the expansion.  Use single quotes to save your sanity.

As noted in the comments below this, this can also be contracted to:

```
sed 's/##\([a-zA-Z_]\{3\}\)##/${\1}/'
```

This answer assumes that the example wanted exactly three characters matched.  There are multiple variations depending on what is in between the hash marks.  The key part is remembering part of the matched string.

Comment: You are assuming exactly three characters between the hash marks. Even so, you could collapse that by turning [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_] into [a-zA-Z_]{3} .

Comment: And the question does just request 3 'X'; I agree that it could be clearer whether the characters in between can be variable in number.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "##foo##" | sed 's/##/${/;s//}/'
```

- `s` change only 1 occurence by default
- `s//`take last search pattern used so second s take also `##` and only the second occurence still exist

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '##XXX##' | sed "s/^##\([^#]*\)/##$\{\1\}/g"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sed 's/\([^a-z]*[^A-Z]*[^0-9]*\)/(&)/pg
```

Comment: It is wrong.It doesn't give the valid answer what he expected.read the question carefully.

Comment: Please read [answer] and always remember that you are not merely solving the problem at hand, but also educating the OP and any future readers of this question and answer. Thus, please [edit] the answer to include an explanation as to why it works.